# How to handle Connection Reset By Peer exception of TIdHTTP.Get request?

Tags: delphi, indy, http-get, delphi-10.1-berlin, connection-reset

In my VCL application, I use `TIdHTTP.Get()` to retrieve data from a RESTful web service. In my application, I use the following code:

```
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  ws: WideString;
begin
  ws := HTTP.Get('http://www.restfulwebservice.com/' + ObjectId);
end;
```

My application always runs on a Windows workstation, and I never want to close it. However, from time to time, it reports a nasty exception *Connection Reset By Peer*. This usually happens after some inactivity.

In such cases, I must close the application and re-open it again, because I have no idea how to handle this exception. I want to properly handle it (within a `try..except` block?) to re-open the connection, so there is no need to close and re-run my app.

Are there any practices on how to catch and handle the above mentioned exception? My research showed me some examples of `TIdTCPServer`, but not `TIdHTTP`.

Im using Delphi Berlin 10.1 Subscription Update 2 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: You are not calling `HTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create` before calling `HTTP.Get()`. Yes, you need a `try..except` around `Get()`, try calling `HTTP.Disconnect` in it. If you are reusing the same `TIdHTTP` object each time, also try setting `HTTP.Request.Connection:='close';` if you are not making frequent requests. Otherwise, call `HTTP.Free` when done, and then call `TIdHTTP.Create` again next time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, sure I call `HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil)` earlier in my code. The lines above are just pseudo-code for brevity. However you pointed to a right thing: I call `TIdHTTP.Create(nil)` in `FormCreate` event and free the object in `FormClose`! Now I understand that is completely wrong. Remy, please copy your comment to the answer, so I can accept it. And again: THANK YOU. You've been the most helpful as usual.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating a single `TIdHTTP` object per Form instance. That alone is not what is causing your issue.  More likely the real issue is that `TIdHTTP` is using HTTP 1.1 keep-alives by default, and you are just leaving the HTTP connection open for awhile, so the server eventually times out and closes its end of the connection, which `TIdHTTP` does not detect until the next time you use it.  So either disable keep-alives, or else handle the error and retry the request.